# Graph of small radius and maximum degree must be small [Diestel's book]

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I was wondering how to show that $|D_{i+1}|\leq (d-1)|D_i|$ in a rigorous way? I understood what the author says when wrote that "because every vertex in $D_{i+1}$ is a neighbor of a vertex in $D_i$ and each vertex in $D_i$ has at most $d-1$ neighbors in $D_{i+1}$".

By rigorous I mean that we need to show that $D_{i+1}$ is a subset of some set whose cardinality is $(d-1)|D_i|$. I have spent some time trying to formalize it but I failed. I'd be thankful to see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You write that

> We need to show that $D_{i+1}$ is a subset of some set whose cardinality is $(d−1)|D_i|$

but that's a needlessly restrictive way to show that $|D_{i+1}| \le (d-1)|D_i|$.

Letting $D_{\le i} = D_0 \cup \dots \cup D_i$, we can write $D_{i+1}$ as the union $\bigcup_{v \in D_i} (N(v) - D_{\le i})$. In words: for each vertex $v$ in $D_i$, take all its neighbors that are not already in one of $D_0, D_1, \dots, D_i$.

We have $|N(v)| \le d$ by assumption. Moreover, $|N(v) \cap D_{i-1}| \ge 1$: each vertex in $D_i$ must have a neighbor in $D_{i-1}$. Therefore $|N(v) - D_{\le i}| \le d-1$.

The size of the union is at most the sum of the sizes of the sets we're combining: therefore
$$
   |D_{i+1}| = \left|\bigcup_{v \in D_i}(N(v)-D_{\le i})\right| \le \sum_{v \in D_i} |N(v) - D_{\le i}| \le \sum_{v \in D_i} (d-1) = (d-1)|D_i|.
$$

Comment: Hi Misha! Thanks a lot for your reply. I guess this what I  was looking for but I did not go too deep to the details. Will take a look tomorrow. Thanks Misha!